# Relationship of all windows handle in a specifc programs

Tags: c#, winapi

In C#, I want to get all active windows handle of a specific program.

For example, I want to get Outlook client and all Outlook opened Mail windows. There could be 2/3/etc mail windows opened. I can not use active window Title to get some sort of relationship, because it could be completely different.

I can use EnumWindows, IsWindowVisible to get a list of all opened windows. Is there any relationship between child windows or group of windows (i.e all windows related to Outlook, all windows related to Skype, etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you planning to *use* this information? There may be better solutions if we know what you're planning to do.

Comment: Thanks. Solution objectives at this stage to get all windows opened in a program group (i.e. all Outlook opened mail windows) then check which one editable/composing.

Comment: But to what end? Are you intending to interact with that window in some manner? Or trying to pull information from it? Or something else?

Comment: Since you say that you're using C#, the System.Windows.Automation namespace seems to be most useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WinAPI in this case.
First, every window is associated with an owner process - use GetWindowThreadProcessId.
Second, all windows have parent/child relations - use EnumChildWindows and GetParent.